# Installing React project as symlink shows vulnerability warnings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to share React components between a web project and desktop project. I found this article that details how to do so while not ejecting from create-react-app.

https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/sharing-source-code-and-libraries-in-react-bd30926df312

In short, it says:
- Create two React projects with CRA, one with the shared components and another that will be consuming them.
- Install the shared project in the consumer project as a symlink with `npm install "../shared-project"`.
- Use `react-app-rewired` and `customize-cra` to make Babel compile everything in the common folder.

Although, after using `npm install  "../shared-project"` I get the following:

```
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\jest.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\jest as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\jest
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\rimraf.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\rimraf as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\rimraf
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\svgo.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\svgo
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\svgo as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\svgo
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\js-yaml.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\js-yaml
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\js-yaml as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\js-yaml
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\browserslist.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\browserslist
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\browserslist as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\browserslist
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\semver.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\semver
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\semver as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\semver
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\esparse.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate.cmd as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\esvalidate as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\esprima
npm WARN rm not removing D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\.bin\esparse as it wasn't installed by D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\esprima

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.1.4 postinstall D:\Projects--Tests\Project\web\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.4 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.0.7 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ shared@0.1.0
added 126 packages from 43 contributors, removed 190 packages, updated 1297 packages and audited 1794232 packages in 314.002s
found 14108 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 14104 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

If I continue with the steps detailed above everything works but what worries me the most is the `3 moderate, 14104 high, 1 critical` message. I don't what to look past it. Any idea how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Literally run - 'npm audit fix' in your command line, it says it just below

Comment: I already did it, it says:
`fixed 0 of 14108 vulnerabilities in 1794232 scanned packages 14108 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated`.